# Sharepoint Accessdenied page - Redirect URL

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I wanted to add some custom functionality to accessdenied page.
So i wanted to find out from where the user was redirected to AccessDenied page.
I was able to find out the Site or web using the following way.

Guid siteId = SPContext.Current.Site.ID;
Guid webId = SPContext.Current.Web.ID;

Now i wanted to find out al list level as well as at folder level from where the user is getting redirected.

I have tried to use the below statement.
String URL = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.Query
list = web.GetList(URL);
But i am getting an error since the URL was not properly formatted.
Below the string value that i am receiving for the URL.

http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FPDF%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx%3FRootFolder%3D%252fPDF%252fSample%26FolderCTID%3D%26View%3D%257b84DFEB5F%252d1F81%252d433A%252dB11C%252d007D1BCB3C8C%257d

From the above url how to find the list and folder value.

Thanks,
Sudan

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following solutions:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ketaanhs/archive/2010/03/13/moss-sharepoint-2007-custom-error-page-and-access-denied-page.aspx

http://balajinjl.wordpress.com/2008/06/18/customizing-access-denied-page-in-moss-2007/